# VSCode not using correct version of pip to install packages

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, pip, package, python-venv

**Trying to install packages using pip inside my venv results in them being installed globally instead of within my venv.**

I have found a workaround but I would love to not have to use it. Perhaps I've been unknowingly been telling vscode to install packages globally upon creation of my venv's?

- I am on Windows 10
- In cmd I can confirm that I am in the correct venv: *(venv) Z:\path\to\cwd*
- I have selected the correct interpreter within vscode as well. *same venv as above*

***pip --version*** points to another location within a different drive: *pip 23.1.2 from C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)*
***where pip*** also points to: *C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe*

My current workaround is to change the directory within cmd to *Z:\path\to\cwd\venv\Scripts* and then run the *pip install package* command.

It's not a terrible workaround, but I'm confused why VSCode automatically uses the version of pip located within my C:\ drive instead of the version located within the venv.

Is there a way to change this within VSCode?